# What's the difference: Creating structure pointer inside a structure of the same type with the keyword struct

Tags: c++, c, oop, struct

Coming from a C++ background here. I'm required to write C for my one of my courses, which I've never been exposed to. What's' the difference beteween these two declarations? Why include the struct keyword? Are there different meanings? Do they have different meanings in C++ vs C?

```
struct A {
    int dataA;
    A* nextA;
};

struct B {
    int dataB;
    struct B* nextB;
};
```

The comments below say that the first is invalid in C. However, I'm compiling just fine with gcc.

[image]

Edit: I was compiling a .cpp file with gcc. I'm such a noob lol.

Solution: The the second is required for C where the first is only valid in C++.

Comment: The first one is not valid in C

Comment: Hmm.. It compiles just fine with gcc.

Comment: Hmmm ... nops http://ideone.com/A24jsZ :)

Comment: gcc compiles both C and C++ code. In your case, your filename `test.cpp` indicates a C++ file.

Comment: `test.cpp` means C++. Use `test.c` for C

Comment: Ahh I see. I'm such a noob. But that cleared it up.

Comment: If you want to use the first form in C, declare a `typedef` before, [like this](http://ideone.com/A24jsZ), but take a look to [typedef is evil, and other truisms](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware1/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=10506)

Comment: Don't post images of text! And why should two different languages have identical semantics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct B {
    int dataB;
    B* nextB;
};
```

is the same as

```
struct B {
    int dataB;
    struct B* nextB;
};
```

in C++ but not in C. When using C, you'll have to use the second form. The first form is not legal C.